# Python library for dealing with time associated data?

Tags: python

I've got some data (NOAA-provided weather forecasts) I'm trying to work with. There are various data series (temperature, humidity, etc), each of which contains a series of data points, and indexes into an array of datetimes, on various time scales (Some series are hourly, others 3-hourly, some daily). Is there any sort of library for dealing with data like this, and accessing it in a user-friendly way.
Ideal usage would be something like:

```
db = TimeData() 
db.set_val('2010-12-01 12:00','temp',34) 
db.set_val('2010-12-01 15:00','temp',37) 
db.set_val('2010-12-01 12:00','wind',5) 
db.set_val('2010-12-01 13:00','wind',6) 
db.query('2010-12-01 13:00') # {'wind':6, 'temp':34}
```

Basically the query would return the most recent value of each series.
I looked at scikits.timeseries, but it isn't very amenable to this use case, due to the amount of pre-computation involved (it expects all the data in one shot, no random-access setting).

Comment: Other than SQLite which you already have? Or other than `datetime` package that you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is sorted you can use the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) module to quickly get the entry with the greatest time less than or equal to the specified time.

Something like:

```
i = bisect_right(times, time)
# times[j] <= time for j<i
# times[j] > time for j>=i
if times[i-1] == time:
      # exact match
      value = values[i-1]
else:
      # interpolate
      value = (values[i-1]+values[i])/2
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) has a date type. You can also convert all the times to seconds since epoch (by going through `time.gmtime()` or `time.localtime()`), which makes comparisons trivial.

Comment: Well, but that's not quite it. I basically need to be able to query for times that don't actually exist in the source data. That's the key to this. I basically need 'fuzzy' matching. I mean, I know how to break down and do this at a lower level, basically treating as a resampling problem, but I had hoped there was a higher-level way of doing it.

Comment: So...you want all matches later than time X. Query where the time field is > X.

Comment: I don't think there is a generic higher level way, because there are a variety of options for interpolation between values (linear or cubic, for example).

Answer (score 0):

It is a classic row-to-column problem, in a good SQL DBMS you can use unions:

```
SELECT MAX(d_t) AS d_t, SUM(temp) AS temp, SUM(wind) AS wind, ... FROM ( 
  SELECT d_t, 0 AS temp, value AS wind FROM table 
     WHERE type='wind' AND d_t >= some_date
     ORDER BY d_t DESC LIMIT 1
  UNION
  SELECT d_t, value, 0 FROM table
     WHERE type='temp' AND d_t >= some_date
     ORDER BY d_t DESC LIMIT 1
  UNION
  ...
) q1;
```

The trick is to make a subquery for each dimension while providing placeholder columns for the other dimensions. In Python you can use SQLAlchemy to dynamically generate a query like this.